# Cann't play/preview the audio content which filename include emotion icon

Tags: android, audio, frameworks

============

Download a audio content(MP3) from website *See you again.mp3* and rename to 
*See you [image] again.mp3*

*See you again.mp3* Can play/preview mp3 with GooglePlay **BUT**

*See you[image] again.mp3* can NOT be played/previewed with GooglePlay,a **Permission Denial** was thrown like below:

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/40 from pid=1532, uid=1000 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()**

Could anyone help me to answer my doubts --> **Why Android throw the Permission Denial**

PS: LG Nexus still exist this issue

[image]

[image]